# Connecting string and number commands in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to add movement commands plus the amount that must be moved into a list. I cannot figure out how to get it the desired output. The following is my code

```
import re

history_list = []

gameOn = True

while gameOn:
    user_command = input("Please enter a direction and amount to move: ")
    history_list += re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  user_command).split()
    if user_command.lower() == "off":
        break

print(history_list)
```

So I have 2 basic movement commands that is 'forward' and 'back' that also takes a number that I want to move forward or backward and then a 'left' and 'right' command that turns left or right.
lets say I type "forward 20" then "right" then "back 15"
What I get is

`['forward','20,'right','back','15']`

But what I want is

`['forward 20','right','back 15']`

Comment: Why do you use `split()`?

Comment: To split the user_command into a list

Comment: If the user enters the commands one by one, can you not just add them like so: `history_list.append("forward 20")`, `history_list.append("right")`, etc.? Maybe you need to add a separate function to validate or format what the user enters but it seems the splitting as you have it now is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you are using this complicated construct with a regular expression and split because you think that it's needed to append to a list. It's not, you could rewrite it as this:

```
history_list = []

gameOn = True

while gameOn:
    user_command = input("Please enter a direction and amount to move: ")
    history_list.append(user_command)
    if user_command.lower() == "off":
        break
    
print(history_list)
```

However, since you are taking input from a user, you will want some validation of the inputs where a regular expression and `split` might be useful, but once you have validated that input, you could just re-add the initial input as shown here.